# Compiling J2ME from a Java SE application

Tags: java, java-me, compilation

I created a wrapper for some java mobile applications (J2ME jars). The wrapper calls the game file after it gets started. To wrap a particular jar file, I of course have to compile my wrapper program.

To automate the wrapping process, I created a Java SE application that takes the location of the jar files and wrap them with my program, compile them using the J2ME libraries, and put the wrapped jar file into another location.

This compilation gives a "class version mismatch" runtime error when running on the device or emulator. Is there any solution to this problem?

How do we successfully compile a J2ME applicaiton from a Java SE application?

Comment: I think J2ME applications are targeted for 1.4. Can you compile all of your classes for 1.4 (use `javac -target 1.4`) and see if that works?

Comment: @martijno according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_ME), Java Me is targeted for `1.3` (class version 47.0) not for `1.4`